# Помогите модифицировать фукнцию в php

Tags: php

Есть функция, которая заменяет русские буквы на латиницу, т.е привет => privet, а мне нужно чтобы она наоборот privet => привет. Т.е сделать ее "наоборот".
Новую функцию писать не охото, т.к много букв, поэтому подскажите что можно сделать с этой. P.S они должны быть идентичны.

```
function translit($str) 
{
    $str = mb_convert_case($str,MB_CASE_LOWER,"UTF-8");
    $tr = array(
        "А"=>"A","Б"=>"B","В"=>"V","Г"=>"G",
        "Д"=>"D","Е"=>"E","Ж"=>"J","З"=>"Z","И"=>"I",
        "Й"=>"Y","К"=>"K","Л"=>"L","М"=>"M","Н"=>"N",
        "О"=>"O","П"=>"P","Р"=>"R","С"=>"S","Т"=>"T",
        "У"=>"U","Ф"=>"F","Х"=>"H","Ц"=>"TS","Ч"=>"CH",
        "Ш"=>"Sh","Щ"=>"SCH","Ъ"=>"","Ы"=>"YI","Ь"=>"",
        "Э"=>"E","Ю"=>"YU","Я"=>"YA","а"=>"a","б"=>"b",
        "в"=>"v","г"=>"g","д"=>"d","е"=>"e","ж"=>"j",
        "з"=>"z","и"=>"i","й"=>"y","к"=>"k","л"=>"l",
        "м"=>"m","н"=>"n","о"=>"o","п"=>"p","р"=>"r",
        "с"=>"s","т"=>"t","у"=>"u","ф"=>"f","х"=>"h",
        "ц"=>"ts","ч"=>"ch","ш"=>"sh","щ"=>"sch","ъ"=>"y",
        "ы"=>"yi","ь"=>"","э"=>"e","ю"=>"yu","я"=>"ya",
   "."=>"_"," "=>"-","?"=>"_","/"=>"_","\\"=>"_",
   "*"=>"_",":"=>"_","*"=>"_","\""=>"_","<"=>"_",
   ">"=>"_","|"=>"_"
    );
    return strtr($str,$tr);
}
```

Comment: так допиши этот массив "А"=>"A","B"=>"Б","V"=>"В","G"=>"Г" ....

Comment: @mountpoint я вначале хотел так сделать, но это слишком долго. поэтому спрашиваю, можно-ли как то решить этот вопрос альтернативным способом? может цикл поможет?

Comment: есть идея, пропустите массив $tr через функцию array_flip. Она меняет местами ключи и значения массива

Comment: @mountpoint не помогло :(

Comment: Еще есть варианты? Пробовал подмену ключей, не помогло.

Comment: Заполните массив по образцу и получите искомое:

    function translit($str, $detranslit=false){
        $arr= Array(
            Array("SCH", "YA", "Y"), // сначала длинные потом короткие
            Array("Ш", "Я", "Й")
        );
       $key= $detranslit ? 1:0;
        return str_replace($arr[1-$key], $arr[$key], $str);
    };

Comment: @reinraus а по-другому никак? с моей функцией не получится? просто я ее писал под себя, мне именно она нужна.

Comment: А почему бы не написать другую функцию под себя? В чем Вы видите проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вот моя, она также переводит с кириллицы в латиницу, но тут все в отдельных массивах, их можно просто местами переставить в str_replace:

```
public static function slugify($string){

    $rus = array('ё','ж','ц','ч','ш','щ','ю','я','Ё','Ж','Ц','Ч','Ш','Щ','Ю','Я');
    $lat = array('yo','zh','tc','ch','sh','sh','yu','ya','YO','ZH','TC','CH','SH','SH','YU','YA');

    $slug = str_replace(
        explode(' ', 'А Б В Г Д Е З И Й К Л М Н О П Р С Т У Ф Х Ъ Ы Ь Э а б в г д е з и й к л м н о п р с т у ф х ъ ы ь э'),
        explode(' ', 'A B V G D E Z I J K L M N O P R S T U F H _ I _ E a b v g d e z i j k l m n o p r s t u f h . i . e'),
        str_replace($rus, $lat, $string));

    return strtolower(str_replace(array(' ', '.', ','), array('-', '', ''), $slug));
}
```